# data.table aggregation to list column

Tags: r, data.table

I'm trying to aggregate a data from a data.table to create a new column which is a list of previous rows. It's easier to see by example:

```
dt <- data.table(id = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3), letter = c('a','a','b','c','a','c','b','b','a'))
```

I would like to aggregate this in such a ways that the result should be

```
   id  letter
1:  1 a,a,b,c
2:  2     a,c
3:  3   b,b,a
```

Intuitively I tried

```
dt[,j = list(list(letter)), by = id]
```

but that doesn't work. Oddly enough when I go case by case, for example:

```
> dt[id == 1,j = list(list(letter)), by = id]

   id      V1
1:  1 a,a,b,c
```

the result is fine... I feel like I'm missing an `.SD` somewhere or something like that...

Can anybody point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Update:** The behaviour `DT[, list(list(.)), by=.]` sometimes resulted in wrong results in R version >= 3.1.0. This is now fixed in [commit #1280](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/commit/86276f48798491d328caa72f6ebcce4d51649440) in the current development version of [data.table](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table) v1.9.3. From [NEWS](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blob/master/README.md):

> - `DT[, list(list(.)), by=.]` returns correct results in R >=3.1.0 as well. The bug was due to recent (welcoming) changes in R v3.1.0 where `list(.)` does not result in a *copy*. Closes [#481](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/481).

With this update, it's not necessary for `I()` anymore. You can just do: `DT[, list(list(.)), by=.]` as before.

---

This seems to be a similar issue as the known [bug #5585](https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=5585&group_id=240&atid=975). In your case, I think you could just use

```
dt[, paste(letter, collapse=","), by = id]
```

to fix your problem.

As @ilir pointed out, if it is actually desirable to get a list (rather than the displayed character), you could use the workaround suggested in the bug report:

```
dt[, list(list(I(letter))), by = id]
```

Comment: upvoted, beat me to it..although this doesn't return the variable name "letter"

Comment: This issue is because `list(.)` shallow copies in R3.1.0. Will be fixed for next release.

Comment: Good to know the reason. Thanks Arun. I found another way to do it using `.SD` but this works just the same. I didn't benchmark the runtime between to see which is better.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax below works for me:

```
dt[, list(lst=list(letter)), by=id]
```

I am using R version 3.0.3, data.table_1.9.2.

Comment: Does it really give the desired result? For me, it just gives `b,b,a,c` for all id's. Using R 3.1.0, data.table_1.9.2

Comment: Works as intended on my version. It must be the bug @shadow is pointing out. The bug report has a workaround as well.