# Unlist nested list columns in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

Unlist nested list column in data.table. Assuming all the list elements are the same type. The list elements are named, the name has to be handled also.
It is somehow opposite operation to [data.table aggregation to list column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23288509/data-table-aggregation-to-list-column).
I think it is worth to have it in SO [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table) knowledge base.
My current workaround approach below, I'm looking for a little bit more canonical answer.

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(
    a = letters[1:3], 
    l = list(list(c1=6L, c2=4L), list(x=2L, y=4L, z=3L), list())
)
dt[]
#    a      l
# 1: a <list>
# 2: b <list>
# 3: c <list>
dt[,.(a = rep(a,length(l)),
      nm = names(unlist(l)),
      ul = unlist(l)),
   .(id = seq_along(a))
   ][, id := NULL
     ][]
#    a nm ul
# 1: a c1  6
# 2: a c2  4
# 3: b  x  2
# 4: b  y  4
# 5: b  z  3
# 6: c NA NA
```

Comment: Can't you just do `dt[, .(nm = names(unlist(l)), ul = unlist(l)), by = a]`?

Comment: The last row, which has an empty list, is not handled in that way.

Comment: @jangorecki, Are empty lists also always unnamed?

Comment: @AnandaMahto Hard to say now, in my use case I assume named list would not be empty but store some dummy `NA` or `integer()`.

Comment: If your empty list is at the start this workaround will not work because `data.table` will not be able to determine the type of column for the result.

Comment: I'm curious what use case you have in mind when you say it's important to have this in the knowledge base..? Like `lm` class objects? I've only ever had list columns containing unnamed string vectors.

Comment: @Frank more or less the same what `tables()` function do, but I want to collect more metadata. E.g. column types: `data.table(name = "dt", coltypes = list(list(col1="integer", col2="character")))`. @Simon good point.

Comment: @jangorecki But the inner object does not need to be a list in that case. Doesn't this also serve the purpose? `data.table(name = "dt", coltypes = list(c(col1="integer", col2="character")))`

Comment: for coltypes (`typeof`) yes, but for colclasses (`class`) no, as the single column can have multiple classes. Anyway that particular case is not part of the question. So yes in that question I could use `c` instead of `list`, of course then the last empty list would need to be 0 length integer.

Comment: @Frank see related work [demo](https://rawgit.com/jangorecki/5664c3d90ec6213a63d5/raw/bb434646a1596b2110bf3bc8cd4edc28dd9940c0/information_schema.html), if you have any thoughts I would be glad to hear - GMTs chat.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not sure it is more "canonical" but here is a way to modify `l` so you can use `by=a`, considering you know the type of your data in list (with some improvements, thanks to @DavidArenburg):

```
dt[lengths(l) == 0, l := NA_integer_][, .(nm = names(unlist(l)), ul = unlist(l)), by = a]

#   a nm ul
#1: a c1  6
#2: a c2  4
#3: b  x  2
#4: b  y  4
#5: b  z  3
#6: c NA NA
```